# Producing n rows per group

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

It is known that `GROUP BY` produces one row per group. I want to produce multiple rows per group. The particular use case is, for example, selecting two cheapest offerings for each item.

It is trivial for two or three elements in the group:

```sql
select type, variety, price
from fruits
where price = (select min(price) from fruits as f where f.type = fruits.type)
   or price = (select min(price) from fruits as f where f.type = fruits.type
      and price > (select min(price) from fruits as f2 where f2.type = fruits.type));
```

([Select n rows per group in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463140/select-n-rows-per-group-in-mysql))

But I am looking for a query that can show `n` rows per group, where `n` is arbitrarily large. In other words, a query that displays `5` rows per group should be convertible to a query that displays `7` rows per group by just replacing some constants in it.

I am not constrained to any DBMS, so I am interested in any solution that runs on any DBMS. It is fine if it uses some non-standard syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any database that supports analytic functions\ window functions, this is relatively easy

```
select *
  from (select type, 
               variety, 
               price,
               rank() over ([partition by something]
                            order by price) rnk
          from fruits) rank_subquery
 where rnk <= 3
```

If you omit the `[partition by something]`, you'll get the top three overall rows.  If you want the top three for each `type`, you'd `partition by type` in your `rank()` function.

Depending on how you want to handle ties, you may want to use `dense_rank()` or `row_number()` rather than `rank()`.  If two rows tie for first, using `rank`, the next row would have a `rnk` of 3 while it would have a `rnk` of 2 with `dense_rank`.  In both cases, both tied rows would have a `rnk` of 1.  `row_number` would arbitrarily give one of the two tied rows a `rnk` of 1 and the other a `rnk` of 2.

Comment: You should use `row_number()` rather than `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.  As I read the question, that is the correct answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Maybe (which is why I included the discussion on ties).  Frequently, people say they want 5 rows but if there is a tie for fifth, they may not be happy having the tie broken arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2):

To save anyone looking some time, at the time of this writing, apparently this won't work because https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html.

I've never been a fan of correlated subqueries as most uses I saw for them could usually be written more simply, but I think this has changed by mind... a little. *(This is for MySQL.)*

```
SELECT `type`, `variety`, `price`
FROM `fruits` AS f2
WHERE `price` IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT `price` 
   FROM `fruits` AS f1 
   WHERE f1.type = f2.type
   ORDER BY `price` ASC
   LIMIT X
   )
;
```

Where X is the "arbitrary" value you wanted.

If you know how you want to limit further in cases of duplicate prices, and the data permits such limiting ...

```
SELECT `type`, `variety`, `price`
FROM `fruits` AS f2
WHERE (`price`, `other_identifying_criteria`) IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT `price`, `other_identifying_criteria`
   FROM `fruits` AS f1 
   WHERE f1.type = f2.type
   ORDER BY `price` ASC, `other_identifying_criteria` [ASC|DESC]
   LIMIT X
   )
;
```

Comment: I assume that `=` should be `IN` here. It doesn't do exactly what I need, because if there are duplicate prices it will produce more rows than I want, but it might be good enough in practice.

Comment: Yeah, that should have been `IN`. Corrected.

Comment: @Ishamael, not sure if questioners get notified of edits, but I added something to possible address the multiple at price scenario.

Comment: Also, `ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`. Version is 5.5.43

Comment: Pfft, it was worth a shot. I guess correlated subqueries are still useless to me. :|

Answer (score 1):

"greatest N per group problems" can easily be solved using window functions:

```
select type, variety, price
from (
  select type, variety, price,
         dense_rank() over (partition by type) order by price as rnk
  from fruits
) t
where rnk <= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows functions only work on SQL Server 2012 and above. Try this out:

### SQL Server 2005 and Above Solution

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE(Category VARCHAR(50), SubCategory VARCHAR(50), price INT)
INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  ('Meat','Steak',1),
        ('Meat','Chicken Wings',3),
        ('Meat','Lamb Chops',5);

DECLARE @n INT = 2;

SELECT DISTINCT Category,CA.SubCategory,CA.price
FROM @yourTable A
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (@n) SubCategory,price
    FROM @yourTable B
    WHERE A.Category = B.Category
    ORDER BY price DESC
) CA
```

Results in two highest priced subCategories per Category:

```
Category                  SubCategory               price
------------------------- ------------------------- -----------
Meat                      Chicken Wings             3
Meat                      Lamb Chops                5
```