# Getting more rows per group using groupBy in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to write an eloquent query which returns up to 3 rows per group (using groupBy). [This post is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130928/producing-n-rows-per-group) but I'm not sure how to apply that solution here.

I have an eloquent model `Deal` for my MySQL table deal. Each deal can have one of four `types`, so ultimately there should be at most four groups (or less if there are no deals of a certain `type`).

I have tried `Deal::where('status', 'active')->groupBy('type')->get();` and this returns an array of four objects (one deal for each of the four types), however I am expecting 12 deals, 3 per group (and they do exist in the DB). Similarly, trying `Deal::where('status', 'active')->groupBy('type')->take(3)->get();` returns an array of three objects (one group is now missing).

I've accomplished this so far by making four separate DB queries, one for each of the four types but I'd prefer it if this can be done in one. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

One of the way you can achieve what you are trying to do is:

```
Deal:where('status', 'active')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('type')
    ->map(function($deal) {
        return $deal->take(3);
    });
```

Of course, you need to check whether the query returns `null` or `empty` objects and please note that the query returns all the *active* `Deal`(s) (the filtering happens on the `Collection`) which might be non-efficient if there are lots of `Deal`(s)

Answer (score 1):

You should call `groupBy` on the collection, not on the query:

```php
Deal::where('status', 'active')->get()->groupBy('type');
```

To restrict the query itself to only return the maximum of 3 per group, refer to the article you linked to in your original question.

Comment: I don't know that this would work because `Deal::where('status', 'active')->get()` could return an array of objects so doing groupBy on that collection would return a "Trying to get property of non-object" error...I believe.

Comment: Moving groupBy to the collection allows groups to contain more than 3 results since it lacks a limit. If I were to place a limit on the collection then it limits the number of groups, not the number of results per group.

Comment: @MilesP - which is why I said you should refer to your linked article to restrict the results to N per group. This cannot easily be done with the query builder. You need SQL variables and ranking. Read [this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) for more information on N per group SQL.